# Attachments must be parented to a base part. Roblox Error

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have a LocalScript that fires a RemoteEvent that adds a trail to the user and takes it away. The issue is on line 8 of the server script and it says that the Attachment must be parented by a base part (head) even though head is a MeshPart so it should work.
This is the local script.

```
local char = player.Character
local humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local head = char:WaitForChild("Head")
local HRP = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local speed = 16 
local maxSpeed = 100
local FlashTrail = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("FlashTrail")
local DeleteFlashTrail = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("DeleteFlashTrail")
local function onKeyPress(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        if player:GetAttribute("Flash") == true then
            humanoid.WalkSpeed = maxSpeed
            FlashTrail:FireServer(head, HRP)
        end
    end
end

local function onKeyRelease(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        if player:GetAttribute("Flash") == true then
            humanoid.WalkSpeed = speed
            DeleteFlashTrail:FireServer(head, HRP)
        end
    end
end

game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(onKeyPress)
game:GetService("UserInputService").InputEnded:Connect(onKeyRelease)
```

This is the serverside script.

```
local DeleteFlashTrail = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("DeleteFlashTrail")
FlashTrail.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(head, HRP)
    local trail = game.ServerStorage.Trail:Clone()

    trail.Parent = head

    local attachment0 = Instance.new("Attachment",head)

    attachment0.Name = "TrailAttachment0"

    local attachment1 = Instance.new("Attachment",HRP)

    attachment1.Name = "TrailAttachment1"

    trail.Attachment0 = attachment0

    trail.Attachment1 = attachment1
end)

DeleteFlashTrail.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(head, HRP)
    head.TrailAttachment0:Destroy()
    HRP.TrailAttachment1:Destroy()
    head.Trail:Destroy()
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a RemoteEvent's FireServer function, the [engine provides the player that fired it as the first argument](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent#OnServerEvent). For example, if you call `FireServer(a, b, c)` you'll get `OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, a, b, c)`

Looking at your code : `OnServerEvent:Connect(function(head, HRP)`, the error is telling you that `head` isn't a BasePart, and that's because it is a Player.

To fix both of your OnServerEvent connections, add a variable to account for the player.

```
OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, head, HRP)
```